# what does the number of censors represent?

Tags: survival, censoring

I'm trying to understand the [ggsurvplot](https://www.r-pkg.org/pkg/survminer) and I stumble about how to interpret the number of censors, like here:

[image: img]

why is it 0 at the start and max = 2 halfway through and at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a description of the underlying data.

A survival time is right-censored when the last observation is made on an individual at that time and the individual hasn't yet had the event. The plot of "censorings" is just how many individuals had such a right-censored observation at the indicated time, color coded in this case according to male/female. The times with `n.censor` values of 2 are just times when 2 individuals instead of 1 had right-censored observations.

Those censoring times are also seen in the vertical hashes along the survival curves.

Comment: Thank you, so, in case of an observation of deaths this means like "Dude, are you alive?" => "Yes, I am" => "Censored!" ? What is a censor in terms of machine failures? Resp. what does it mean, when those censors above would represent machines?

Comment: @Ben with a machine that would be that the machine hadn't yet failed when you stopped collecting the data.  (At some point you have to stop collecting data and analyze what you have. If you wait for the last machine to fail you might wait a very long time.) You know that such a machine lasted at least as long as you had observed it, but you don't know how much longer.

Comment: @Ben censoring is a fundamental concept in survival analysis that deserves close study. [This review by Leung et al.](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.publhealth.18.1.83) in Annual Review of Public Health 18: 83-104 (1997) is one place to start.

Comment: Thank you! But the number of machines, which have not been failed, yet, wouldn't that simply be a single amount of machines at the very last time step?

Comment: @Ben that depends on study design. If you start all the machines at the same `time = 0`, watch them all for a period of time, and don't add new machines to the study when those fail, then there would be no censoring at early times and "a single amount" at the very last time. If you study machines put into service by customers at different times and set `time = 0` as the service-entry date for _each individual machine_, then on that elapsed-time scale there can be censoring at almost any time point. The "very last time" would be for whichever had the longest service duration without failure.